# Academic rank equivalence between the UK and the US systems

Tags: career-path, professorship

What are the US equivalent ranks to the Lecturer, Senior Lecturer, Reader (or Associate Prof), Professor ranks of the UK system?
Is it correct that in the US system they are Assistant Prof, Associate Prof, Full Prof and Chair/Endowed Prof, respectively?
I know that in the British system, there are further sub-levels in each of these ranks whereas in the US system there is no further gradation within each rank. So I am looking for only rough equivalence.

Edit: It would be great if a formal/informal reference which compares the two is also pointed out.

Comment: What is the point of academic rank? In the military, the point of rank is to remind you of where you are on the hierarchy.  Wouldn't funding awards do the same thing in academia.

Comment: Academic rank often corresponds with pay scale (sometimes with the possibility of bonusses). Often it also corresponds with a set of tasks that the person is expected/required to perform. It also corresponds with where persons are in the hierarchy, i.e. who has power over whom. As to the latter there are significant country and discipline differences. All of these are differences that are not covered by funding awards.

Comment: I'm not sure there's all that much equivalence between one UK institution and another.... ;-)

Comment: @John What kind of sub-levels are you referring to in the UK? The salary pay spine? Because (unless my University is special), there is no such thing as "Level 3 Senior Lecturer" :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the wiki pages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_(United_States) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_in_the_United_Kingdom:

1. Entry level position

   - UK: Lecturer
   - USA: Assistant Professor
2. Mid-level

   - UK: Senior Lecturer
   - USA: Associate Professor
3. Upper-level

   - UK: Reader
   - USA: Professor
4. Highest level

   - UK: Professor
   - USA: Endowed Chair/Named Professor

Note 1. that in the USA, ranks #2 and higher are normally tenured. Tenure is handled different in the British system.

Note 2. The American rank of a named chair (aka named professorship, endowed chair) is distinct from the administrative head of a department, who is also often called the "Chair."

Comment: "Tenure is handled different in the British system." what is that different process?

Comment: "what is that different process", the difference is that there is no tenure in the UK system that is equivalent to the US system. However, in the UK all employees of an organisation (any organisation) have the right not be to dimissed without a good reason and due process once they have been employed for 2 years.

Comment: @IanSudbery I idly wonder whether universities in England, Scotland and Wales _did_ have tenure equivalent to the US system, prior to the enactment of sections 203(1)(a)-(c) of the Education Reform Act 1988.  Either way, I note that Cambridge University's probationary policy still uses the name "confirmation of tenure" for the process whereby an Assistant Professor becomes an Associate Professor (Grade 9).

Comment: Yes. They did used to have tenure in the US sense. I'm sad to hear that Cambridge is following the herd and adopting US style job titles - lecturers do actaully lecture, where as assistant professors are nobodies assistant.

Comment: @IanSudbery Cambridge is actually moving ahead of the herd of UK universities by abolishing the old titles altogether.  It's also interesting that Cambridge is mapping "Reader" to "Professor (Grade 11)", whereas I think most other UK universities that have adopted a mapping map both "Senior Lecturer" and "Reader" to "Associate Professor".  In the Cambridge case, I'll miss the old titles too, but my disappointment is tempered by the fact that I'm always very pleased when a decision is made by an actual ballot of the Regent House, rather than by any variety of executive sneakiness.

Comment: Havn't many universities already moved over? I thought at very least Oxford, Warwick, Birmingham and Edinburgh had abolished the british titles, and moved to the US ones.

Comment: @IanSudbery  AIUI, Oxford still uses L-SL-R-P as the official titles, but allows its Readers to call themselves "Professor" on external correspondence; and Warwick has hybrid titles like "Associate Professor (Reader)" and "Associate Professor (Senior Lecturer)" (as does my former workplace, Plymouth University).   I _think_ Cambridge is unique in having decided to scrap the old titles (for newly-appointed staff) completely.

Comment: The oxford website lists only the titles of Associate Professor and Professor on its academic pay structure page, and this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_in_the_United_Kingdom#Research_and_teaching_career_pathway_at_Oxford lists "Departmental Lecturer" in addition to those two titles, but suggests such individuals are not considered part of the permeant faculty of the university.

Comment: @IanSudbery You're right.  Which raises the interesting subsidiary question of where the badly out-of-date copy of Oxford's statute XII that I downloaded and read a few weeks ago came from.

Comment: By coincidence, the anchor on the BBC News Channel has just introduced an interviewee as a Reader at the University of Birmingham, and he didn't object.

Answer (score 5):

Some new data: the University of Cambridge [recently decided](https://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/reporter/2020-21/weekly/6601/6601.pdf#page=31) to phase out the titles "lecturer", "senior lecturer", and "reader", adopting the following mapping of old titles to new titles:

- Lecturer (who is still on probation) -> Assistant Professor
- Lecturer (who has already passed probation) -> Associate Professor (Grade 9)
- Senior Lecturer -> Associate Professor (Grade 10)
- Reader -> Professor (Grade 11)
- Professor -> Professor

Answer (score -3):

Information in Wikipedia is not to be taken for granted. I woould rather suggest the following according to different categorisations in different countries
Lecturer is usually someone holding an MA (at least in most of the countries I know)
Senior Lecturer usually somewhere between MA and PhD
Assistant Professor definitely with PhD
Associate Professor with habilitation 
Full Professor habilitation + many publications

Comment: My question was specific to the UK (and the British system). @RoboKaren's answer is correct - I have checked with several British academics as well.