# Assistant professor vs lecturer in the UK

Tags: phd, graduate-school, professorship, lecturer, assistant-professor

I have been looking at various graduate programs in the UK, and noticed a lot of people under the title "lecturer" taking incoming PhD students. I've completed some graduate studies on a master's level in the United States. Would doing a PhD under the supervision of a "lecturer" be different than doing one under the supervision of a professor? I read online that in the UK, "lecturer" is analogous with "assistant professor". Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: This question might help you out: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48977/academic-rank-equivalence-between-the-uk-and-the-us-systems

Comment: To address the part of your question that isn't explicit in the linked answer: no, there is no inherent difference between doing a PhD under a 'lecturer' rather than under a 'professor' (except, perhaps, that a UK professor will typically be much further along in their career; see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/168444/what-are-the-risks-and-benefits-of-being-the-first-phd-of-a-new-supervisor/168570 for some perspectives on this).